# jQuery: resize DIV after all AJAX calls are loaded within a .getScript call

Tags: jquery, ajax, height

I'm having trouble resizing a DIV after all the content is loaded with jQuery. My HTML page is the following:

**html**

```
    <div id="limit" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="contentpanel>
                //Data from global.js is inserted here
                <div id="display_visitor_graph"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $.getScript("controller/ucp/global.js>", function() {
                     var height = $("#limit").height();
                     $(".contentpanel").css('height',height);
                }); 
           });
```

**example of ONE of the AJAX calls in global.js**

```
function loadGraphData(startDate, endDate)
{
    $.getJSON("controller.php",
    {   
        type: "monitor",
        command: "graph",
        start: startDate.format("{yyyy}-{MM}-{dd}"),
        end: endDate.format("{yyyy}-{MM}-{dd}")     
    }, 
    function(data)
    {       
        Morris.Area(
        {
            element: "display_visitor_graph",
            data: data.labels,
            xkey: "date",
            ykeys: ["total", "unique"],
            labels: ["Views", "Visitors"],
            gridTextColor: "#151515",
            gridTextSize: "12",
            gridTextFamily: "'Open Sans', HelveticaNeue, Helvetica, Arial",
            hideHover: true,
            pointSize: 3,
            parseTime: true,
            behaveLikeLine: true,
            resize: true,
            smooth: false,              
            lineColors: ["#2A6184", "#472A53"],
            fillOpacity: 0.65
        });
    });     
};
loadGraphData(startDate, endDate);
```

Now the global.js file contains about 10 .getJSON AJAX calls to generate different types of data to populate graphs, tables, fields, etc located in the .contentpanel.

With the current code the var height is the height when the 10 AJAX calls haven't been processed yet, causing an overspill of containers once the content is loaded from the AJAX calls within the global.js. How do you make it that the height of the .contentpanel is set once all the AJAX calls within the global.js are executed?

Comment: Have you tried setting the height to `auto`?

Comment: How (or where) do you insert the received data into `.contentpanel`?

Comment: I tried to set height to auto, no luck. When I console.log the var height it gives the height when the data isn't inserted into the .contentpanel yet. I need the get the height after the data is loaded and inserted.

@kmsdev I have the HTML mark up in the .contentpanel, but the data is fetched and inserted in the global.js file. Imagine a getJSON call that fetches the data and than populates a Datatable or Graph marked with HTML in the .contentpanel.

Comment: The problem is that you have too ajax calls and you can't know when you can set the height. Check my answer and tell me if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

*I think* that this solution should works:
Set a counter as global var. In each ajax call, increment the counter. In each response, decrement it. An easy way to do it:

```
var ajaxcounter = 0;

$(document)
    .ajaxStart(function(){
        if( ajaxcounter !== null ) ajaxcounter++;
    })
    .ajaxStop(function(){
        if( ajaxcounter !== null ){
            ajaxcounter--;
            if( ajaxcounter == 0 ){
                // do stuff
                ajaxcounter = null;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I see the logic in this approach, however, is there any more practical solution for addresing this problem or is this the only way?

Comment: As I understand, you are loading data through ajax. Then, How do you know when required data (.contentpanel) is loaded? I mean, the ajax calls have an order when you send them, but the received data is unordereded. You shouldn't have crossbrowser problems. It no makes sense here

Comment: The other way you have is to do your stuff in the ajax function who loads the `.contentpanel` data

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by including the following snippet after loading the JS file.

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function()
{
    var height = $("#limit").height();
    $(".contentpanel").css("height", height);
    $(".contentpanel").css("background-color", "#e4e7ea");
});
```

By measuring the the height after .ajaxStop I was able to get the neccesary height. However, for some reason I also had to reasign the background color of the DIV to make it completely work.

Full new code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.getScript("controller/ucp/js/global.js");
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function()
{
    var height = $("#limit").height();
    $(".contentpanel").css("height", height);
    $(".contentpanel").css("background-color", "#e4e7ea");
});
</script>
```

**Edit/Note**
It appears that this works on Firefox 29.0 Ubuntu, but not on Chromium 34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu. No other browsers have been tested. I will update this post once I have found a cross-browser solution.